# EINVAL on connect() in strace output while pinging

Tags: c, system-calls, ping, icmp, strace

I'm doing simple `ping 192.168.205.206` and can see in a strace:

```
...
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 4
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1025), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.205.206")}, 16) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
...
```

however when I do `ping 192.168.205.127`, strace is:

```
...
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 4
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1025), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.205.127")}, 16) = 0
...
```

Seems inside the connect() syscall something weird happened.

At this host there is very complicated routing table and network setting.

When I do `ip r get 192.168.205.206`, strace is:

```
...
socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW|SOCK_CLOEXEC, NETLINK_ROUTE) = 3
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, [32768], 4) = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, [1048576], 4) = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_NETLINK, 11, [1], 4)  = 0
bind(3, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, 12) = 0
getsockname(3, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=26471, groups=00000000}, [12]) = 0
sendmsg(3, {msg_name(12)={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, msg_iov(1)=[{"$\0\0\0\32\0\1\0\311m*^\0\0\0\0\2 \0\0\0\0\0\0\0\20\0\0\10\0\1\0"..., 36}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 36
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(12)={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, msg_iov(1)=[{"8\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\311m*^gg\0\0\352\377\377\377$\0\0\0\32\0\1\0\311m*^"..., 32768}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 56
write(2, "RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argum"..., 36RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument
...
```

but strace of `ip r get 192.168.205.127`:

```
...
socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW|SOCK_CLOEXEC, NETLINK_ROUTE) = 3
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, [32768], 4) = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, [1048576], 4) = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_NETLINK, 11, [1], 4)  = 0
bind(3, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, 12) = 0
getsockname(3, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=3070, groups=00000000}, [12]) = 0
sendmsg(3, {msg_name(12)={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, msg_iov(1)=[{"$\0\0\0\32\0\1\0\ro*^\0\0\0\0\2 \0\0\0\0\0\0\0\20\0\0\10\0\1\0"..., 36}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 36
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(12)={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, msg_iov(1)=[{"p\0\0\0\30\0\0\0\ro*^\376\v\0\0\2 \0\0\376\0\0\1\0\2\0\0\10\0\17\0"..., 32768}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 112
...
write(1, "192.168.205.127 via 169.254.0.1 "..., 71192.168.205.127 via 169.254.0.1 dev bond0.33 src 100.10.1.2 uid 0 
) = 71

...
```

What is the reason of `Invalid argument` and how to understand it from the output or by performing other steps (probably reading kernel source)?

Comment: @red0ct , may I ask, why have you changed the post ?

By changing `linux-kernel` with `C` tag we miss the idea of the question - why kernel returns EINVAL. There is nothing with `C`, at least when I was asking I did not consider C

Comment: Just read `linux-kernel` tag description: *"for questions about the internals of the Linux kernel itself - particularly about writing code that runs within the context of the kernel"*. It has almost nothing to do with Linux kernel internals. But this is definitely related to particular `C` API.